# Json to Gson - Modeling

Tags: json, model, gson

I'm trying to convert a JSON to GSON , but I can not model. Can anyone give me an example with this one.

```
[
    {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "lalala",
        "object1": [
            "string1",
            "string1",
            "string1"
        ],
        "object2": [
            "anotherString1",
            "anotherString2"
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "name": "laaaaalala",
        "object1": [
            "string1",
            "string1",
            "string1"
        ],
        "object2": [
            "anotherString1",
            "anotherString2"
        ]
    }
]
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go.

```
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.List;

import com.google.gson.Gson;

public class Foo
{
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
  {
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    Thing[] things = gson.fromJson(new FileReader("input.json"), Thing[].class);
    System.out.println(gson.toJson(things));
  }
}

class Thing
{
  String id;
  String name;
  String[] object1;
  List<String> object2;
}
```