# How to work with an JSON response which gives me an Array with Objects to setup my ListView

Tags: arrays, object, react-native, flux

I have a View Component which has a ListView filled with JSON data. I use FLUX Pattern for my DataFlow. 
Now when i get a JSON response, "_userNews", which has multiple arrays, with objects inside each array, how is the best way to print out my ListView items? The Objects contains one array and 4 strings. I need the array items from the object as well as 2 strings which i would like to print out in my ListView.
I am a noob in programming and just trying to struggle through the programmers world and learning. Maybe someone has a hint for me how to work with Arrays/Objects.

Answer (score 0):

Some tips:

- Use GSON to map your JSON to a class model.
  Eg: [Json to Gson - Modeling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6300920/json-to-gson-modeling)
- Use the model's toString or a new api toListItemString to be used with ListView.

  ```
  class Thing
  {
      String id;
      String name;
      String notRequired;
      List<String> object2;

      public String toListItemString(){
          return this.id + "\n" +  this.name + "\n" + Arrays.toString(object2);
      }
  }
  ```

Do share a sample JSON for more specific response.

Comment: Does this work for React Native too? I used GSON in my Android / Java Project a long time ago, but didn´t know that this works for JavaScript too...

Comment: Not sure if I understood it correctly. For GSON/JS I found a link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22777930/javascript-gson-access-json-references-dynamically-over-object-graph-circular