# How can I convert date-time value from Json to Gson

Tags: android, json, gson

I want to convert this json value to gson value. I'm able to get most of the data, the only place i'm getting stuck is field "time".
Can anyone help me out, Please.

```
"quantity_map": {
    "https://example.com/abc/500/": {
        "available": 4,
        "requested": 1,
        "max": 4,
        "id": "500",
        "amount": {
            "2015-12-02": 3000.0,
            "2015-12-01": 3000.0,
            "2015-11-30": 3000.0
        },
        "time": "2015-11-27 11:46:38.612147+00:00"
    },
    "https://example.com/abc/499/": {
        "available": 5,
        "requested": 1,
        "max": 5,
        "id": "499",
        "amount": {
            "2015-12-02": 5500.0,
            "2015-12-01": 5500.0,
            "2015-11-30": 5500.0
        },
        "time": "2015-11-27 11:46:38.621023+00:00"
    }
}
```

Json to gson conversion code

```
for (Map.Entry<String, Object> mapEntry : quantityMap.entrySet()) {
                final String key = mapEntry.getKey();
                Log.d(TAG, mapEntry.getValue().toString());
                ConversionClass value = new ConversionClass();
                try {
                    value = new GsonBuilder()
                            .setDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.ssssssZ")
                            .create()
                            .fromJson(mapEntry.getValue().toString(), ConversionClass.class);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
```

ConversionClass.class

```
public class ConversionClass{

private int available;
private int requested;
private int max;
private int id;
private HashMap<String, String> amount = new HashMap<>();
private Date time;

public void setAvailable(int available) {
    this.available = available;
}

public void setRequested(int requested) {
    this.requested = requested;
}

public void setMax(int max) {
    this.max = max;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public void setAmount(HashMap<String, String> amount) {
    this.amount = amount;
}

public void setTime(Date time) {
    this.time = time;
}

public int getAvailable() {
    return available;
}

public int getRequested() {
    return requested;
}

public int getMax() {
    return max;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public HashMap<String, String> getAmount() {
    return amount;
}

public Date getTime() {
    return time;
}
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Json to Gson - Modeling](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6300920/json-to-gson-modeling)

Comment: Can please explain me, I'm not getting you. :)

Comment: hey, i'm facing problem time field only....rest i'm able to convert...Thanks

Comment: Can you please show us the code for json to gson conversion ?@hArsh

Comment: @Soham - I added the code for conversion, above now.

Comment: @hArsh declare variable String time rather than Date time.

Comment: That is also not working, its giving exception " Unterminated object at line 1 column 197 path $.time"

Comment: To generate Modal class use jsonscheme2pojo.org website. It will automatically generate the POJO classes for you. I tried out with your JSON value and for the time field, it produced String variable.

Comment: @4k3R - I'm unable to create a class in that, can you guide me in that too.. Thanks :)

Comment: @4k3R - Thanks, it worked for me ;)

Comment: Well, try using third party services for these kind of jobs. It will improve your productivity a lot. jsonschema2pojo.org

Comment: @4k3R - Thanks, will surely try :)